# result.getFieldErrors() returns Field names Instead of Error Message in SPRING MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Validator to Validate some Field in My Web App.

Here is the Code to Add Error Message on some Conditions:

```
errors.rejectValue("firmDetailFo.firmName", "",
                        "Enter Proper Firm Name");
```

While **Debugging** the BindingResult result Object gives the the following result:
**org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors**

```
    Field error in object 'firmFo' on field 'firmDetailFo.firmName': rejected value []; codes [firmFo.firmDetailFo.firmName,firmDetailFo.firmName,firmName,java.lang.String,]; arguments []; default message [Enter Firm Name]
    Field error in object 'firmFo' on field 'firmDetailFo.dateOfFile': rejected value []; codes [firmFo.firmDetailFo.dateOfFile,firmDetailFo.dateOfFile,dateOfFile,java.lang.String,]; arguments []; default message [Select Date Of File]
    Field error in object 'firmFo' on field 'firmDetailFo.dateOfFirmOpening': rejected value []; codes [firmFo.firmDetailFo.dateOfFirmOpening,firmDetailFo.dateOfFirmOpening,dateOfFirmOpening,java.lang.String,]; arguments []; default message [Select Date Of Firm Opening]
```

and **result.getFieldErrors()** has the Following

```
[Field error in object 'firmFo' on field 'firmDetailFo.firmName': rejected value []; codes [firmFo.firmDetailFo.firmName,firmDetailFo.firmName,firmName,java.lang.String,]; arguments []; default message [Enter Firm Name], Field error in object 'firmFo' on field 'firmDetailFo.dateOfFile': rejected value []; codes [firmFo.firmDetailFo.dateOfFile,firmDetailFo.dateOfFile,dateOfFile,java.lang.String,]; arguments []; default message [Select Date Of File]
```

**My Jsp Code to show Errors:**

```
<p class="error">
            <form:errors path="firmFo.*" cssClass="name2" />
            
        </p>
```

[image: Actual Result]

[image: Expected Result]

Any Suggestions....???

Comment: Do you want to iterate `FieldErrors` ?

Comment: @shantaram_t No This piece of Code done the iteration <form:errors path="firmFo.*" cssClass="name2" /> perfectly. It works fine with other pages

Answer (score 0):

The name is Problem here

So i just added a Duplicate Object inside the FO

```
 private FirmDetailFo firmDetailFo1;
```

and Replaced the Fo with the duplicate one inside the validator

```
errors.rejectValue("firmDetailFo1.firmName", "",
                        "Enter Proper Firm Name");
```

Now it works fine As expected :)